# Local emulator for website that uses gyroscope and https

Tags: android, reactjs, android-emulator, panoramas

I am creating a website with react and in that website I load a panorama using [photo sphere viewer](https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/) . When the website is visited by a mobile device, I want to use the mobile's gyroscope to pan around the panorama.

How do I test it locally? I need an HTTPS connection to be able to access the gyroscope. I also need something to emulate the movement and gyroscope of an android device.

How can I set up such an environmet? I want to access `https://localhost:3000/view` locally via a device emulator somehow.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Developper of Photo Sphere Viewer here, I had the same issue when testing the gyroscope plugin. I ended up using https://localtunnel.github.io/www/